# Errors when trying to open Gnome System Monitor

Tags: debian, kde, gnome-system-monitor

I have Debian 10 and KDE Plasma. gnome-system-monitor had been working perfectly for 10 months, and all of a sudden when I try to open it in KDE I get this error:

```
 gnome-system-monitor

 (gnome-system-monitor:28523): Gtk-WARNING **: 14:51:50.934: Theme
 parsing error: gtk.css:127:35: The style property
 GtkButton:child-displacement-x is deprecated and shouldn't be used
 anymore. It will be removed in a future version

 (gnome-system-monitor:28523): Gtk-WARNING **: 14:51:50.935: Theme
 parsing error: gtk.css:128:35: The style property
 GtkButton:child-displacement-y is deprecated and shouldn't be used
 anymore. It will be removed in a future version

 (gnome-system-monitor:28523): Gtk-WARNING **: 14:51:50.935: Theme
 parsing error: gtk.css:129:34: The style property
 GtkCheckButton:indicator-size is deprecated and shouldn't be used
 anymore. It will be removed in a future version

 (gnome-system-monitor:28523): Gtk-WARNING **: 14:51:50.935: Theme
 parsing error: gtk.css:130:36: The style property
 GtkCheckMenuItem:indicator-size is deprecated and shouldn't be used
 anymore. It will be removed in a future version

 (gnome-system-monitor:28523): Gtk-WARNING **: 14:51:50.935: Theme
 parsing error: gtk.css:132:46: The style property
 GtkScrolledWindow:scrollbars-within-bevel is deprecated and shouldn't
 be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version

 (gnome-system-monitor:28523): Gtk-WARNING **: 14:51:50.935: Theme
 parsing error: gtk.css:135:30: The style property
 GtkExpander:expander-size is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore.
 It will be removed in a future version

 (gnome-system-monitor:28523): Gtk-WARNING **: 14:51:50.936: Theme
 parsing error: gtk.css:142:29: The style property
 GtkStatusbar:shadow-type is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore.
 It will be removed in a future version

 (gnome-system-monitor:28523): glibmm-CRITICAL **: 14:51:50.990: 
 unhandled exception (type Glib::Error) in signal handler: domain:
 g-io-error-quark code  : 0 what  : Unable to find default local file
 monitor type
```

I have no idea what this means or why it started happening.

Comment: Does [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1171204/1001338) help you?

Comment: I just tried that and got this: "gnome-screensaver: no process found"